# Visual Studio Extensibility Resources

Tags: visual-studio

Anyone know of any good resources for getting up and going with Visual Studio Extensibility (tutorials, etc.)?  There seems to be little around the net as far as I can see.  Or mayabe I'm just using the wrong keywords in Google.

What I'm generally having trouble with, at the moment, is navigating through a solution and accessing code files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you mean exactly by 'code-model'. A good place to start is MS [VSX learning center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx/bb980955.aspx).  A complete chart of the exposed object model is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/za2b25t3.aspx). There's also a chance that what you're after is FileCodeModel, in which case you can google it directly (or alternatively ProjectItem.FileCodeModel), and you'd get many [examples](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2006/mz2006017.aspx) and [references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.filecodemodel(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: This is pretty much what I had in mind. Working with this API is a real bitch though!

Comment: I've spent a few hours on MSDN website and still can't understand how to create a simplest VSIX extension from scratch. For example, add a menu item. MSDN is full of usual crap no one needs to read about and has no quickstarts. What a hell?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fantastic resource with a ton of HOW-Tos:
[Resources at MZ-Tools](http://www.mztools.com/resources_vsnet_addins.aspx)

Comment: +1 Looks like several of those are out-dated, compared to VS2008. And then there is VS2010 just around the corner, which changes a lot.

Comment: There's a lot there so I'm not surprised. If you have any good links feel free to add an answer or list them here so I can add them to the list.

Comment: could you find a tutorial how to create a vs2010 extension from scratch? That wizard-generated poo doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Sorry I've stopped working on my VS extension (for 2008).  I don't have any good resources to point you to outside of what you'd get from a simple Google search.